# How do I remove overlapping faces?

Tags: faces

I've tried to select all, remove faces, invert from another post etc... however my faces still overlap. It's one mesh, here's a photo. The overlapping is very apparent where the objects intersect.

[image]
 [image]

Comment: if you've removed doubles and it begins to destroy your mesh, I'm afraid you need to correct your mesh manually

Comment: It doesn't destroy the mesh, it just doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: so I guess you need to work manually, maybe share your file

Comment: Okay, I'll add it to the main post.
Do I just upload it to Mediafire?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and put the URL of this page before uploading

Comment: Okay, it's uploaded to the post.

Comment: your topology is not good, for example when you cross two perpendicular rectangles you don't just duplicate one and rotate it 90°, you need to create edge loops and extrude...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your topology is not good, for example when you cross two parallelepipeds you don't just duplicate one and rotate it 90°, you need to create edge loops, extrude or bridge, etc... so that faces don't overlap. Also try to work with quads.

Note that in some cases it's ok to just intersect meshes (for example if the pieces don't need to appear welded).

[image]